# Logo with text in title page above title

Tags: formatting, positioning, titles, logos

I am new to latex and I must make a lab report at my university . I am trying to put a logo on top left of the title page with text right next to it, above title, but without successful result. I saw some questions of other people here but everytime I make changes something else messes up. Can you help me and post the correct code for that? I want to do exactly that in the picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,usenames,dvipsnames,modern,plain,newlogo]{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\LaTeX}
\lhead{\gr title}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{\gr title}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}



\begin{document}

    \en

    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image.jpg}
    \end{figure}

    \gr

    \title{\textbf{title}}
    \author{\textbf{name}\\Α.Μ.: \textbf{012345}}
    \date{\today}

    \maketitle

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{image.png}
    \end{figure}

    \pagenumbering{gobble} 


    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}


   \end{document}
```

Comment: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=30567&sid=00cb4fdb81b98d025d3a2e2c1ec4a6f4 Crosspost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a titlepage as far as I can understand. Here is a way to use it:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,usenames,dvipsnames]{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\LaTeX}
\lhead{\gr Τίτλος}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{\gr Όνομα}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\long\def\mytitle{%
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\end{minipage}\hspace{10pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}%
\textsc{\color{brown}%
ΕΘΝΙΚΟ ΜΕΤΣΟΒΙΟ ΠΟΛΥΤΕΧΝΕΙΟ\\
ΣΧΟΛΗ ΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΩΝ ΑΕΡΟΣΚΑΦΩΝ ΠΡΙΝ ΤΗΝ ΠΤΩΣΗ\\
ΠΛΗΡΟΦΟΡΙΚΕΣ ΚΑΙ ΑΛΛΑ ΠΟΥ ΤΑ ΞΕΡΟΥΝ ΟΛΟΙ\\
ΕΡΓΑΣΤΗΡΙΟ ΔΙΚΤΥΩΝ ΥΠΟΛΟΓΙΣΤΩΝ}\\%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[thick, brown] (0,0)--(0.99\textwidth,0);%   
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{center}



\vspace{1cm}
{\centering

        {\scshape\Large Πολυτεχνικό Πανεπιστήμιο\par}
        \vspace{1.5cm}
        {\huge\bfseries Τίτλος εργασίας\par}
        \vspace{2cm}
        {\Large\itshape Ονομα Επώνυμο\par}
        \vfill
        επιβλέπον\par
        Αθανάσιος \textsc{Επιβλεψίδης}

        \vfill

% Bottom of the page
        {\large \today\par}
        }
\end{titlepage}
}


\begin{document}

        \gr

 \mytitle

 Συνέχεια εδώ

\end{document}
```

I just removed your command `\maketitle` and added `\mytitle` which is defined before the `\begin{document}`. It includes your titlepage that you will change to your needs. example-image-a will be replaced from a photo of your university logo.

Output title:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Works perfect!!! One question, when I run the code: in \mytitle , a message says : there is no  line to end.- unknown command

Comment: @orion13 I edited... Just check it again... Copy paste the \mytitle definition and tell me if there is still a problem

Comment: @orion13... tikz needed. I rejected your edit at first time because you was deleting tikz package... But accepted after. I had to replace it. If you don't want tikz, just ask me to replace the part of the code needs it

Comment: No its perfect, it was my mistake.

Comment: @orion13... I know you are not a greek... But I can not let you like this in the danger of using the same text next to the image that I provided. (I am good today...). So, Just change it to be like the picture's if you really need this. If you would change it to something else, it is ok... Bu DO NOT let it like I have it here :P

Comment: Thank you again! Don't worry, I made those changes!!! :)