# Creating a header design with a logo with LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I am very new to LaTeX and just trying to add a formatting expected by my school.

I only have the logo available. So the double lines should be added. I go crazy because I already spent 3 hours and can't make it work.... Could you please help me how to get the design below in LaTeX:

[image]

All I have right now is this logo :

[image]

Could someone help me how to add a double line to the middle of the logo which goes all the way to the right till the end of the line and also add some text above the double line and below as well.

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit:
What I did in overleaf (but it did not work):

```
    \newcommand{\doublerule}1[.4pt]{%
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.7ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \rule[0.3pt]{\linewidth}{#1}}
```

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{L}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{cimeres_fejlec.PNG}

`\ Obudai Egyetem   
 \doubleline
 \bla bla bla

\end{wrapfigure}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code of what you've tried?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the greeting. I am working in overleaf. I have added my vode to the main post.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396349/logo-with-text-in-title-page-above-title/396357#396357 may be a good start for a MWE... But sure can be better... (Welcome! Try to change that code -remove greek- and give it as a MWE)

Answer (score 2):

Next time please give us a complete minimal working example (MWE), it helps us to help you.

I created the following MWE to get a titlepage similar to that what you described:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\LaTeX}
\lhead{left head}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\newcommand{\doublerule}[1][.4pt]{% <===================================
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.7ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \rule[0.3pt]{\linewidth}{#1}\par} % <=================================


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  \end{minipage}\hspace{10pt}
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}%
    \raggedleft\bfseries%
    Obudai Egyetem\\
    \doublerule  % <====================================================
    blind text to show the first line of text\\%
    and the second line\\
  \end{minipage}%
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
{\centering
  {\scshape\Large titlepage\par}
  \vspace{1.5cm}
  {\huge\bfseries and other informations\par}
  \vfill
  {\large \today\par}
}
\end{titlepage}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]